# Filling Datatable through linq

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, crystal-reports

I'm new to linq and trying to understand it. I'm trying to fill a data table through linq but getting an error in the sql command adapter.
Below is the code which I'm using, don't know if I'm using it the right way!

This is the error I'm getting:

> Error 7   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand'

```
{
        northwindEntities1 nw = new northwindEntities1();
        var query = from c in nw.customers
            join o in nw.orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID // first join
            join od in nw.orderdetails on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID    // second join
            join p in nw.products on od.ProductID equals p.ProductID    // third join
            where c.ContactName.StartsWith("Maria Anders")
            select new {
                o.CustomerID,
                c.ContactName,
                o.OrderID,
                p.ProductID,
                p.ProductName,
                od.Quantity,
                p.UnitPrice
            };
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = query;
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(datatable); // getting value according to imageID and fill dataset

        ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument(); // creating object of crystal report
        crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/custreport.rpt")); // path of report 
        crystalReport.SetDataSource(datatable); // binding datatable
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;

        crystalReport.ExportToHttpResponse
        (CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "PersonDetails");
}
```

Comment: You can simply use `query.ToList()` as data source for the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***A SQL query is not the same as a [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) query, they are totally different.***

LINQ by itself is a set of query language features that used are to query different data sources, but it is not the same as a SQL query. You have miss understand that. So you can't pass it to act like SQL query.

You can't pass `System.Linq.IQueryable` which coming from the variable `linq` to the [MysqLCommand CommandText Property](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommandmembers.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommand-commandtext), you should pass a string which should be the MysQL query not LinQ query. Something like this:

```
    string query = "Select * FROM Customers INNER JOIN ..."; //you have to pass sql query
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = query;
    ...
```